# Getting started with Chrome extension and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting my first chrome extension and I am a bit stuck. I've run through https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

I know how to alter the little pop up page that you create, but I don't know how to allow a tab of a specific domain to be altered with my JavaScript.

This leads onto my second question, I have a local copy of jQuery within the extension and am able to use it in the pop-up page. How do I load jQuery into the tab that I want to alter?

Comment: Next up, read the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (the whole thing, carefully) and the [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) docs.

Comment: Wow - Thanks for voting down a perfectly valid question...

Comment: I doubt the person who downvoted will see your comment. SO seems to be allergic to basic questions that start with "I'm a beginner". Not that I agree.

Comment: Please stop rolling back a perfectly valid edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to give the tabs permission in manifest file. Also for it to access data on specific domain you have to specify in permissions. for eg for it to work on www.google.com

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "*://www.google.com/*"]
```

To add jquery in extension include it in your popup.html as well as add in manifest file as given. Matches for matching urls on which it has to work. Make sure jquery.js to be in same folder as your manifest and popup.html

```
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches": ["*://*.url.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }]
```

look up here
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest